# GY91 IMU module, Interrupt?

Tags: interrupt, imu

Are there interrupt Pin in the GY91 Module?
If not, are there good alternative for periodic sensor reading?
(apart from mcu schedule/external timer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The INT pin of the MPU-9250 is not presented on the IO header of the GY-91.

The *only* way of knowing what is going on inside the MPU-9250 at any time is to go and look. I.e., periodic polling of the sensor.

If you want to use the interrupt pin you will have to shop around for a different module that gives you access to that pin.